# Embedded Jetty - Programmatically add form based authentication

Tags: java, ldap, jetty, forms-authentication

Is there a way to programmatically add Form based Authentication as per below? 
I am using my own `LdapLoginModule`. Initially I use Basic Authentication and it worked OK, but now I want more control on the Login page (like display logo, etc)

Is there any good samples?

I am using embedded jetty v8.1.7 . I don't use any web.xml for embedded jetty. The jetty server is started programmatically.

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Test JAAS Realm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.html</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/error.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a `FormAuthenticator` and set this on your `SecurityHandler` for the `ServletContextHandler`. This code creates a trivial server with 2 servlets. The first servlet responds with a hello messsage to the authenticated user name. The second servlet implements a trivial login form.

You should be able to paste the code into a `main[]` and run (you will need the following jars in your classpath; `jetty-server`, `jetty-servlet` and `jetty-security`). To test, point a browser at `http://localhost:8080`, you should be prompted for credentials (username / password) before seeing a response of `hello username`.

```
Server server = new Server(8080);
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/", ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS | ServletContextHandler.SECURITY);

context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new DefaultServlet() {
  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.getWriter().append("hello " + request.getUserPrincipal().getName());
  }
}), "/*");

context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new DefaultServlet() {
  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.getWriter().append("<html><form method='POST' action='/j_security_check'>"
      + "<input type='text' name='j_username'/>"
      + "<input type='password' name='j_password'/>"
      + "<input type='submit' value='Login'/></form></html>");
    }
}), "/login");

Constraint constraint = new Constraint();
constraint.setName(Constraint.__FORM_AUTH);
constraint.setRoles(new String[]{"user","admin","moderator"});
constraint.setAuthenticate(true);

ConstraintMapping constraintMapping = new ConstraintMapping();
constraintMapping.setConstraint(constraint);
constraintMapping.setPathSpec("/*");

ConstraintSecurityHandler securityHandler = new ConstraintSecurityHandler();
securityHandler.addConstraintMapping(constraintMapping);
HashLoginService loginService = new HashLoginService();
loginService.putUser("username", new Password("password"), new String[] {"user"});
securityHandler.setLoginService(loginService);

FormAuthenticator authenticator = new FormAuthenticator("/login", "/login", false);
securityHandler.setAuthenticator(authenticator);

context.setSecurityHandler(securityHandler);

server.start();
server.join();
```

Comment: Thanks! This was helpful to me, and I was able to make it work.

Comment: This is helpful, but I'm wondering how you knew to do it. The Jetty documentation is... without being rude, sparse. For example `ConstraintMapping` is totally undocumented and Google doesn't provide any information about it at all. Do you have to read the internal Jetty code to learn it?