# How can I disable authentication for a specific servlet/pathSpec?

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, forms-authentication, jetty-9

My code is as follows (referenced [Embedded Jetty - Programatically add form based authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769589/embedded-jetty-programatically-add-form-based-authentication)):

```
    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/", ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS | ServletContextHandler.SECURITY);

    context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new DefaultServlet() {
        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            response.getWriter().append("Hello " + request.getUserPrincipal().getName());
        }
    }), "/*");

    context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new DefaultServlet() {
        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            response.getWriter().append("<html><form method='POST' action='/j_security_check'>"
                    + "<input type='text' name='j_username'/>"
                    + "<input type='password' name='j_password'/>"
                    + "<input type='submit' value='Login'/></form></html>");
        }
    }), "/login");

    context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new DefaultServlet(){
        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            response.getWriter().append("This is the metrics page!");
        }
    }), "/metrics");

    Constraint constraint = new Constraint();
    constraint.setName(Constraint.__FORM_AUTH);
    constraint.setRoles(new String[]{"admin"});
    constraint.setAuthenticate(true);

    ConstraintMapping constraintMapping = new ConstraintMapping();
    constraintMapping.setConstraint(constraint);
    constraintMapping.setPathSpec("/*");

    ConstraintSecurityHandler securityHandler = new ConstraintSecurityHandler();
    securityHandler.addConstraintMapping(constraintMapping);
    TestingLoginService loginService = new TestingLoginService();
    securityHandler.setLoginService(loginService);

    FormAuthenticator authenticator = new FormAuthenticator("/login", "/login", false);
    securityHandler.setAuthenticator(authenticator);

    context.setSecurityHandler(securityHandler);
```

This works, but I want the /metrics servlet not require the user to be authenticated. However, I still want all other paths go to the login & the "Hello" servlet.

The only other solution I can think of is to move the "Hello" servlet to a different path and have the root path just redirect to that path. That way I can set the ConstraintMapping's pathSpec to something that doesn't encompass the /metrics path as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
ConstraintMapping constraintMapping = new ConstraintMapping();
constraintMapping.setConstraint(constraint);
constraintMapping.setPathSpec("/*");
```

Unfortunately, there's no concept of "exclude" with Server Constraint Mappings.

You'll have to add multiple path specs that cover what you want, and just not include the `/metrics` path spec in that list of path specs.

Comment: I ended up putting a page in the root path that redirects to the path with the constraints. That way I can make the /metrics page not affected by it. I wish there was a cleaner way to do this.